# querying the owl ontology

Tags: java, sparql, jena, semantic-web, protege

hey i'm new to semantic web,i see the terms like sparql,jena api,owl api,sparql dl,please explain the terms and what they do exactly like

1. what does it mean by jena and sparql are they same are different api,what is the relation between them,
2. i want to find the semantic distance between concepts,which of the above i could use to do this given an owl file
3. what is difference between protege api and jena api role in it because while setting up protege why do i have jena jar file in it

Its all so confusing,please help to answer these questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer your question(s)

**1. what does it mean by jena and sparql are they same are different api,what is the relation between them,**

Jena is a framework developed by HP Laboratory to manage Ontologies through a Java API. So with Jena you can programatically create, populate and querying your ontology.

Sparql is a language (as SQL) used to query an ontology. It is based on the fact that your ontology can be seeing as a set of triple. So SPARQL use a triple pattern to help you find triple which match in an ontology. For example the following SPARQL query look for person name in a given ontology

```
SELECT ?name
WHERE { 
   ?person is_a Person .
   ?person has  ?name .
}
```

**2. i want to find the semantic distance between concepts,which of the above i could use to do this given an owl file**

What do you mean by semantic distance ? Notions of distance and semantic greatly depend on your application

**3. what is difference between protege api and jena api role in it because while setting up protege why do i have jena jar file in it**

Protege is a tool that help you too graphically build your ontology, it can help you to verify that the ontology is consistent and that all the concepts and properties you want are well created. Protege is not design to help you manage the ontology in production with huge amount of indivudial (Jena help you for that)